# How to remove duplicate from any textbox

Tags: vb.net

Simple question for help my friend. How to remove duplicates from a Text, like Textbox1.text = 1,1,0,2,4,7,9,11,13,2,4 (It is not a linebox textbox.)

Also how can I arrange the string in order from the lowest to the highest?

Comment: Since the coma is duplicated a lot, do you also need it removed?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so we can help you. Without code we cant tell you where it's wrong and why.

Answer (score 2):

Split by comma, take distinct, order by the string, and join back together with comma

```
TextBox1.Text = String.Join(",", TextBox1.Text.Split(","c).Distinct().OrderBy(Function(s) s))
```

Comment: How to remove duplicate

Comment: That is the [Enumerable.Distinct()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=netframework-4.7.2) in the middle of the expression